# Typeahead is not working in AEM 6.1 but working in CQ 5.6.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, java-8, aem

I am having a migration of a project from CQ 5.6.1 to AEM 6.1.

Then as I am testing it, found out that the portion of my code which uses typeahead.bundle.js is not working anymore. As i return to test the project in CQ 5.6.1, it does work fine.

Tried to isolate the concern (get the snippet of the code w/o deplying it to AEM 6.1) and it is working fine.

My initial findings is that AEM 6.1 server alone might cause the typeahead.bundle.js not to work.

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="hogan-3.0.1.js"></script>
<script src="typeahead.bundle.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<row>

<input id="country-search" type="text" class="typeahead form-control" placeholder="Country" title="Enter the terms you wish to search for" />

</row>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var countries = new Bloodhound({
          name: 'countrysearch-countries',
          datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('englishName', 'localName'),
          queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
          limit: 5,
          prefetch: {
           url: 'country.json',
          }
        });
        var countrySuggestionTemplate = Hogan.compile('<p>{{localName}} ({{englishName}})</p>');

        countries.initialize();
        $("#country-search").typeahead(null, {
            displayKey: 'localName',
            source: countries.ttAdapter(),
            templates: {
                suggestion: function(country) {
                    return countrySuggestionTemplate.render(country);
                }
            }
        }).on('typeahead:selected', function (e, datum) {
            window.location = datum.url;
        });
    });
</script>
```

JSON String content of country.json:

[{"url":"http://xxxx.com","localName":"افغانستان","englishName":"Afghanistan"},{"url":"http://xxxx.com","localName":"Shqipëria","englishName":"Albania"},{"url":"http://xxxx.com","localName":"الجزائر","englishName":"Algeria"}]

Note: Please be informed that the HTML script above works fine when not deployed to AEM 6.1.

Hope everyone can help me regrading this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already found an answer.

Seems there's an uninitialized inhouse javascript in aem6 server due to undeclared variables (weird because it works in CQ 5.6.1).

So i decalre explicity the variable and it works fine now.